# ConcurrentModificationException with mutable list from Observer

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, concurrentmodification, mutablelist

Grettings, could someone help me with this, I've already implemented an aux list to add the elements that came from an observer, but still the problem persist, the `ConcurrentModificationException` is happening on the addAll line.

Is inside a Fragment Class, an I had an observer that cames from a manager the project has that provides a list of element that will be displayed on an arraylist

```java
manager.getMutableList()
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { mutableList ->
                val auxList = mutableListOf<CustomClass>().apply {
                    addAll(mutableList)
                }
                if (auxList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    ...
                }

                (recyclerView.adapter as RecyclerAdapter).run {
                    items = auxList
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                    ...
                }
            })
```

This is the stack trace

```java
java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size (ArrayList.java:1057)
java.util.ArrayList.addAll (ArrayList.java:588)
com.project.project.Fragment$setObservers$6.onChanged (Fragment.java:330)
com.project.project.Fragment$setObservers$6.onChanged (Fragment.java:74)
androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify (LiveData.java:131)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you modify your `mutableList` from a thread other than your main thread. The best way too avoid these exceptions is to make your list *immutable* (so just a `List` instead of `MutableList`).

All code that wants to modify it then needs to make an own copy:

```
val copy = list.toMutableList()
copy.add(...)
```